# Is thera a meaning for worth "BLUE" = "GAY"?

Tags: meaning, worth

i want to ask is there in englisch language a meaining for worth BLUE = GAY/HOMOSEXUAL?
Because i found that meaning in Urbandictionary for sentence "Am I blue?":

"2. A question asked that can be taken as literally "Am I gay?" or "Do I seem gay?"

2. Sue: Am I blue?
   Beth: Not really, but the brunette staring at you is."

Or is it a mistake and i can't use BLUE for GAY?

Thanks for answers (and sorry for my english, that is not my native language)!

Comment: You can use whatever you want.  However, "blue" is much more commonly taken to mean "depressed".

Comment: No, you can't use *blue* for "gay" if you care for being understood. If you say "I am blue" to a bisexual person, they will take it to mean you are strictly straight. And if you say it to anyone else, they will take it to mean you are sad. Don't start using Urban Dictionary until you can recite a regular dictionary by heart.